# imported model looks washed out/tinted white

Tags: rendering, texturing, .fbx, emission

I was trying to use a tf2 model I found on scetchfab, but whenever I render the model it looks washed out.[image: render]

It looks like this whether I use cycles or eevee.
The original textures look fine and the render on scetchfab looks fine, so I don't know what the problem is.
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/tf2-heavy-252d49dbdef248399e4b0b4d5751d3c0

Here are the shading nodes for the model.[image]

Comment: just a guess: is the light too bright/too close?

Comment: @blunder that is the confusing part. This render was with a 5000W light source, turning it down to 1000W made to look worse. Moving it away just made it look darker, but not any less washed out.

Comment: set the emission strength to 0 in the principled bsdf

Comment: @Alex thank you that worked! I did spend some time messing with the sliders, but I must have skipped that one. What is emission strength for?

Comment: @Alex well spotted! :D

Comment: @mr.hooman Yw. The emission slider makes your object emit a light, which is why your model was washed out. You can see the effect better if you increase the strength and enable bloom. Btw, you can plug the base color into the emissive color with a low strength value to give your object more of that "unlit" look